# C- read a specific number of words from every line in a text file

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read only the first five characters of every line in a file (including whitespace). Meaning, after the pointer arrives at the the 5th character on a certain line, I want the pointer to then reset to the beginning of the next line, and to keep doing so until it reaches `EOF`.

For example, if I want to read the first 5 characters of every line in a file, it should result in the following:

```
Hello World --->  Hello
blah blah   --->  blah 
Goodbye     --->  Goodb
```

I've tried to achieve this by implementing `fgets`, however I cannot figure out how to reset the pointer after 5 characters have been read:

```
while (feof(inputFile) == 0) {
    fgets(str, 6, inputFile);
```

What's happening is that `fgets` stops at the 5th character, but instead of going to the next line, it continues to read the next 5 characters on the same line.

Is there a way to get `fgets` to start at the next line once 5 characters have been read in? Any alternative methods, which do not implement `fgets`, are also acceptable.

Comment: fgets must be inside the while condition.

Comment: can someone explain why the down vote? I edited it to make it as straightforward as possible...

Comment: I tried putting it in the while condition but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
void trimFile(const char *inputFile, const char *outputFile, int length) {
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    fin  = fopen(inputFile, "r");
    fout = fopen(outputFile, "w");
    char str[length + 1];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, fin)){
        char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
        if(p){
            fputs(str, fout);
        } else {
            int ch;
            while((ch=fgetc(fin))!='\n' && ch != EOF)
                ;
            fprintf(fout, "%s\n", str);
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets(char * str, int num, FILE * f)`  reads up to (num-1) bytes and appends a terminating null char.
If you want to skip the rest of the line and your file is of fixed line length, than you can 
set the position of the filepointer to the end of the line using `fseek ( FILE * f, long int offset, int origin )`.

Comment: @chux Ups. Thanks for hint. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also figured it out, this works:

```
while (feof(fi) == 0) {
    fgets(str, 6, fi);
    while ((c = getc(fi)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
      ;
    }
...
```

This reads 5 characters from every line, `getc` moves the pointer back to the beginning of the next line.